# Filter on huge amount of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have a row with exactly the same columns of a pandas dataframe, same order.
I want to get all index of the dataframe which have completely the same values than my row.
Usually I would do something like that

```
df.index[(df['A'] == row['A']) & (df['B'] == row['B'])...]
```

But I have a hundred or so columns.
Do you know an efficiant way of doing it, without writing everything?

Thanks

---

Edit: Following @Driftr95, I tried something like this:
I should have at least one result each time - the concerned index- but no, "find" is an empty dataframe :-(

```
for index, row in DF.iterrows():
    
    DF_SELECT = DF.loc[index-1:index+1]
    find = DF_SELECT.index[(DF_SELECT==row).all(axis=1)]
    print(find)
```

Comment: try using [`.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) like `df.index[(df==row).all(axis=1)]` [*`(df==row)`* is a DataFrame filled with Booleans btw]

Comment: @Driftr95 thanks but doesn't work - see my edit -. Did I do something bad?

Comment: It *should* work ([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azool.png)). It might be something specific to your `DF`, but I can't imagine what...can you share your DataFrame? Maybe a snippet with the output of `DF.to_dict('tight')` (or `DF.sample(7).to_dict('tight')` if it's large)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` for this. It applies the lambda function to each column in the data frame:

```py
# A sample data frame. We want to find index of all rows
# matching 3, 4, 5
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(-1, 3), columns=["A", "B", "C"])
row = pd.Series([3,4,5], index=list("ABC"))

# The code
cond = df.apply(lambda col: col == row[col.name]).all(axis=1)
df.index[cond]
```